# Websocket 1.0 WebSocketServlet replacement

Tags: java, websocket, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I'm trying to adopt old code that uses (now deprecated) `WebSocketServlet`. The old code looks like this:

```
@Singleton
ExampleServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol, HttpServletRequest request) {
        // Do something
        // ...

        return // StreamInbound impl;
    }
}
```

As I said in the newer version of the tomcat 7 there is WebSocket implementation backported from tomcat 8 (WebSocket 1.0, Tyrus) and class `WebSocketServlet` is deprecated.

What I should use instead to deploy my servlet with newer API?

Comment: Take a look at Atmosphere https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere. It will shield you from all of API changes and will works on Tomcat 7/8 transparently.

Answer (score 5):

With regards to KIC's answer - it is not all what is needed.
Since JSR356 should be used with Tomcat 8.*, you need to modify your class from:

```
class MyWebSocket extends WebSocketServlet
```

to:

```
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint(value="/your-websocket-endpoint")
class MyWebSocket
```

Then, since `StreamInbound` is also deprecated in Tomcat 8.*, you need to write own methods to handle open, close, error and message events:

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

@OnOpen
void onOpen(Session session) { }

@OnClose
void onClose(Session session) { }

@OnMessage
void onMessage(Session session, String message) { }

@OnError
void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) { }
```

Finally, Tomcat provides javax.websocket.* classes already and it should not be included with your application. For Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and for Gradle is:

```
providedCompile 'javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:1.0'
```

Please see related post 
[Tomcat 8 and Websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348686/tomcat-8-and-websocket).

Answer (score 1):

I am answering this old question because tis is the first hit on google if you look for the replacement of WebSocketServlet.

> Replaced by the JSR356 WebSocket 1.0 implementation and will be removed in Tomcat 8.0.x.

So you simply need the javax WebSocket dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and use the annontations or the interfaces described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html

thats it.